# Nach Hackfleischspieß Art?

Tags: grammar, idiom, adjective

Ich war gerade in der Mittagspause und stolperte bei einem Kleinimbiss über folgenden Ausdruck:

> Döner Kebab (nach Hackfleischspieß Art)

Worüber ich mich nun wunderte ist, was dies für eine Konstruktion ist.

Eindeutig ist das in Klammern geschriebene eine explikative Ergänzung zur Bezeichnung "Döner Kebab". Wie aber setzt sich diese zusammen, bzw. ist das grammatikalisch überhaupt korrekt?

Bekannt ist mir dieses `nach XY Art` mit einem Adjektiv:

Beispiel:

> nach ungarischer Art
>   nach französischer Art

Wieso steht hier also ein Substantiv im Nominativ?

Comment: Mich gefällt die Vorstellung, dass sich jemand während seiner Mittagspause bei der Dönerbude um die Ecke mit den grammatikalischen Feinheiten einer Beschilderung auseinandersetzt... :D Hat denn der Hackfleischspießdöner Kebab geschmeckt?

Comment: @Potzblitz aber ja. ausserdem war ich am heutigen tage soweit beschäftigt, dass ich ohne Ablenkung dem Wahnsinn verfallen wäre. Daher nahm ich mir in meiner Mittagspause die Zeit, meine Gedanken schweifen zu lassen ;)

Comment: Darf's auch ein `Schnitzel (nach) Wiener Art` sein?

Comment: @Em1 wenn das Schnitzel nach Wiener Art ist, dann sollte ich wohl auch Chips nach Ungarischer Art kaufen;)

Comment: Ich würde das eher in die Kategorie "mit Scharf oder?" einstufen... :-)

Comment: Im Gegensatz zum Wiener Schnitzel, bei dem Kalbfleisch verwendet werden muss, ist ein Schnitzel Wiener Art eines, bei dem - üblicherweise - Schweineschnitzel wie ein Wiener Schnitzel zubereitet, sprich paniert wird. Bei Döner wird aber soweit ich weiß fast immer Hackfleisch verwendet und nur selten werden Schnipsel von Schwenkbratenscheiben abgesäbelt. Ich vermute aber, dass das die Feinheit schon ist die ausgedrückt werden soll. Vielleicht ist die Substanz aber auch mehr etwas Leberkäs/Wurstiges, was man oft angeboten bekommt, und Hackfleisch demgegenüber schon ein Qualitätsausweis.

Comment: Das wird aber sprachlich durch das einschränkende '... Art' wieder zurückgeholt - ob das beabsichtigt ist, und nicht echtes Hackfleisch zum Einsatz kommt, oder kein Spieß? Vielleicht eine Pfanne? Zum grammatikalischen kann ich leider weiter nichts beifügen.

Comment: *besagt, dass ein Döner nur aus Rind-, Kalb- oder Schaffleischscheiben bestehen und der Hackfleischanteil maximal 60 Prozent betragen darf* https://www.mainpost.de/regional/wuerzburg/der-doener-ist-tot-es-lebe-der-drehspiess-art-9744120 - Hackfleischspieß hat womhl mehr als 60 % Hackfleisch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ich habe folgende Varianten bisher gesehen:

> nach Grossmutters Art
>   nach Grossmutterart
>   nach Bauernart
>   nach schweizer Art

Meine Vermutung wäre, dass die von dir angetroffene Konstruktion grammatikalisch falsch ist und dadurch zustande kam, dass `nach Hackfleischspießart` einfach sonderbar zu lesen wäre.

Comment: +1, wobei die Alternative `nach Hackfleischspieß-Art` von der Optik wahrscheinlich auch keinen großen Unterschied zur Variante mit Leerzeichen machen würde.

Comment: mich würde mal interessieren, wie weit diese konstruktion verbreitet ist. ich bin mir relativ sicher, dass das bei mindestens zwei anderen mir bekannten "Kleinimbissen" in der Umgebung auch so angeschlagen war

Comment: Beim Schnitzel Wiener Art wird Wien auch nicht klein geschrieben und Wienerart nicht als neue Wortverkettung eingeführt.

Comment: „Schweizer“ wird immer großgeschrieben, auch wenn das Wort als Adjektiv vor einem Substantiv steht (s. § 61).